# Ontology merging not working properly using Protege 5.0 or TopBraid Composer

Tags: merge, ontology, protege, topbraid-composer

Both tools just concatenate the ontologies instead of merging them.
For Protege, I have used the option "Refactor -> Merge Ontologies"
For Topbraid Composer, I have used this option: Open one ontology, Import other ontology.

Both tools result in Concatenation. I have used these ontologies:
http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/AmazonWS/1.1/Book.owl - For Book
http://purl.org/net/nknouf/ns/bibtex - for Bietex

Both ontologies have same class of "Book", but tool is not merging them.

Answer (score 2):

The two ontologies do not have `Book`, they have `http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/AmazonWS/1.1/Book.owl#Book` and `http://purl.org/net/nknouf/ns/bibtex#Book`
(This is from eyeballing the namespaces, so I might be slightly off the target)

The identity of a named class is not provided by its IRI fragment, but by the full IRI.

What you're looking for in this case is ontology alignment first, then merging. I don't believe Protege has this feature natively, you'll need some plugin to provide it. I don't know about TopBraid Composer.

Comment: Do you have any idea of Merging tool for Ontologies. I have tried both (Protege and TopBraid) tools with even sample ontolgies with simple classes. Still they are concatenate the classes not merge them.